# Окно ввода логина/пароля в WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

В моей программе на WPF я использую библиотеку MahAps.Metro и при запуске программы я хочу отображать [диалоговое окно](http://mahapps.com/controls/dialogs.html), где можно будет ввести логин/пароль.

Но выдает ошибку `System.InvalidOperationException`. Не пойму, в чем дело.
Может потому что метод, отображающий окно, в конструкторе вызываю?

```
    public MainWindow() // Конструктор
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        LogIn();
    }

    private async void LogIn()
    {
        LoginDialogData result = await this.ShowLoginAsync("Authentication", "Enter your credentials", 
            new LoginDialogSettings { ColorScheme = this.MetroDialogOptions.ColorScheme, InitialUsername = "MahApps" });
    }
```

У меня есть код, обрабатывающий нажатие кнопки. При нажатии возникает диалоговое окно, где можно вести логин/пароль. Внутри обработчика нажатия на копку все работает, но если этот код скопировать в метод выше, то опять будет та же ошибка...

```
    private async void buttonLogOut_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var title = "Enter your credentials";
        var settings = new LoginDialogSettings
        {
            ColorScheme = MetroDialogOptions.ColorScheme
        };
        while (true)
        {
            var result = await this.ShowLoginAsync("Authentication", title, settings);
            if (result.Username == "dima" && result.Password == "123456")
                break;
            title = "Wrong data, try again";
        }
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не должно, по идее. А покажите stack trace из exception'а, а?

Comment: Добавил скриншот. Пишет: `OverlayBox can not be founded in this MetroWindow's template. Are you calling this before the window has loaded?`

Comment: Ну вот видите, вы сами нашли ошибку.

Comment: Напишите не `LogIn();`, а `Loaded += (o, args) => LogIn();`

Comment: Спасибо, получилось. Надо в будущем больше внимания обращать на  сообщения VS

Comment: Вынес в ответ, раз работает :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Исходя из сообщения об ошибке, нужно запускать `LogIn` после загрузки окна:

```
public MainWindow() // Конструктор
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Loaded += (o, args) => LogIn();
}
```